# Ajax/jQuery Autocomplete, odd bug?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, autocomplete

I've used a certain bit of code once before on another site, and it works just fine - it's a jQuery-Ajax-PHP autocomplete plugin that I found, and modified. It runs fine on site y, but here on site x, it automatically defaults the textbox to "" when the user has not selected anything (this occurs onblur) -- that code is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function lookup(inputString) {
        if(inputString.length == 0) {
            $('#suggestions').hide();
        } else {
            $.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
                if(data.length >0) {
                    $('#suggestions').show();
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    } 
    function fill(thisValue) {
        $('#inputString').val(thisValue);
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
    }
</script>
```

while in rpc.php the code is the following [with credentials blanked]:

```
<?php
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['ns_user']; 
    $db = new mysqli('xxxx.com', 'xxxx' ,'xxxx', 'xxxx');

    if(!$db) {
        echo 'ERROR: Could not connect to the database.';
    } else {
        if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
            $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);
            if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
$query = $db->query("SELECT school FROM noteshare_users WHERE school LIKE '$queryString%' GROUP BY school");
                if($query) {
                    while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                        echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$result->school.'\');">'.$result->school.'</li>';
                    }
                } else {
                    echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';
                }
            } else {
            } 
        } else {
            echo 'There should be no direct access to this script!';
        }
    }
?>
```

It's basically an autocomplete form for a list of schools.

I've tried a few things, and nothing seems to fix it! Here's an example of one of the experiments I've tried:

```
    function fill(thisValue) {
if(thisValue==""){
var x = $('#inputString').val();
$('#inputString').val(x);
}
else {
        $('#inputString').val(thisValue);
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
    }
}
```

Does anyone seem to notice anything wrong? Thanks a lot!

Any and all responses are greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you add some view information? If you are using Safari or Firefox (with Firebug), you might be receiving some errors in your console. That might be useful too to understand your question and problem a little better.

Comment: Hi, Bjorn Schijff, there are no errors in the console, I checked prior :( The only problem is that when a user types in data, the data they type in if they don't select anything from the autocomplete list, disappears onblur.

Comment: Ok, are you sure that there is no other code affecting the textbox you're refering to?

Comment: There is a single other jQuery function that runs a function onfocus, but that's just a .fadeIn()  later in the document.